# How to get my program to read third if statement

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I am trying to get my program to move a "sushi plate" clockwise in a rectangular fashion although it won't seem to continue moving after my third `if` statement:

```
from graphics import * 
win =GraphWin("Draw and Animate",640,480)
win.setBackground("wheat1")

#Right
xmove = 1
ymove = 0
#Down
xmove2 = 0
ymove2 = 1
#Left
xmove3 = -1
ymove3 = 0
#Up
xmove4 = 0
ymove4 = -1

sushiplate = Rectangle(Point(300,160),Point(340,180))
sushiplate.setFill("white")
sushiplate.draw(win)

leftsushi = Circle(Point(310,170), 5)
leftsushi.setOutline("Green")
leftsushi.setFill("orange")
leftsushi.draw(win)

rightsushi = Circle(Point(330,170), 5)
rightsushi.setOutline("Green")
rightsushi.setFill("orange")
rightsushi.draw(win)

while(True):
    #Move sushi

    sushiplate.move(xmove4, ymove4)
    leftsushi.move(xmove4, ymove4)
    rightsushi.move(xmove4, ymove4)
    sushicenter = sushiplate.getCenter()
    if (sushicenter.getY()<=130):
        xmove4 = xmove
        ymove4 = ymove 
    if (sushicenter.getX()>=510):
        xmove = xmove2
        ymove = ymove2
    if (sushicenter.getY()>=360):
        xmove2 = xmove3
        ymove2 = ymove3


    update(60)
```

My sushi plate will move up, right, down but will continue moving down and my third `if` statement will not run:

```
if (sushicenter.getY()>=360):
    xmove2 = xmove3
    ymove2 = ymove3
```

Comment: Under what circumstances do you expect the two innermost `if` blocks to be executed?

Comment: I don't see any way for Y to ever be both less than 130 and greater than 360. Same problem with X. How could it be greater then 490 and also less than 120?

Answer (score 1):

These conditions should be at the same level and not nested. Since the second level if checks `sushicenter.getY() <= 130`, then your fourth level condition can only be triggered if `getY()` is both `>=360` and `<=130` and that can never happen.
I think you meant to keep them at the same level so they can be independently triggered and not depend on the other conditions.

```
from graphics import * 
win =GraphWin("Draw and Animate",640,480)
win.setBackground("wheat1")

#Right
xmove = 1
ymove = 0
#Down
xmove2 = 0
ymove2 = 1
#Left
xmove3 = -1
ymove3 = 0
#Up
xmove4 = 0
ymove4 = -1

sushiplate = Rectangle(Point(300,160),Point(340,180))
sushiplate.setFill("white")
sushiplate.draw(win)

leftsushi = Circle(Point(310,170), 5)
leftsushi.setOutline("Green")
leftsushi.setFill("orange")
leftsushi.draw(win)

rightsushi = Circle(Point(330,170), 5)
rightsushi.setOutline("Green")
rightsushi.setFill("orange")
rightsushi.draw(win)

while(True):
    #Move sushi

    sushiplate.move(xmove4, ymove4)
    leftsushi.move(xmove4, ymove4)
    rightsushi.move(xmove4, ymove4)
    sushicenter = sushiplate.getCenter()
    if (sushicenter.getY()<=130):
        xmove4 = xmove
        ymove4 = ymove 
    if (sushicenter.getX()>=490):
        xmove = xmove2
        ymove = ymove2
    if (sushicenter.getY()>=360):
        xmove2 = xmove3
        ymove2 = ymove3
    if(sushicenter.getX()<=120):
        xmove3 = xmove4
        ymove3 = ymove4

    update(60)
```

Comment: I tried putting them back on to the same level, although it still seems to ignore the third if statement and my plate keep on moving down. Do you know why this could be

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't actually try to run this and are not aware it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're already under the `if (sushicenter.getY()<=130):` branch.  `sushicenter.getY()>=360` can't possibly be true in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that once a condition like this triggers:

```
 if (sushicenter.getX()>=510):
```

It continues to trigger every time as the result is a change to the Y direction and the object is fixed in the X direction.  Cases after this one never trigger.  We can fix this by first "testing the waters" to see if the move might trigger a change and then make the movements afterward.  My rewrite of your code below does this but also tries to get rid of numbers in favor of symbols as all the numbered variables were confusing, even to you given the bugs in the code:

```
from graphics import *

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 480
BORDER = 130
RADIUS = 5
DIAMETER = RADIUS * 2

# Right
XMOVE_RIGHT = 1
YMOVE_RIGHT = 0
# Down
XMOVE_DOWN = 0
YMOVE_DOWN = 1
# Left
XMOVE_LEFT = -1
YMOVE_LEFT = 0
# Up
XMOVE_UP = 0
YMOVE_UP = -1

win = GraphWin("Draw and Animate", WIDTH, HEIGHT)
win.setBackground('wheat1')

sushiplate = Rectangle(Point(BORDER - DIAMETER * 2, BORDER - DIAMETER), Point(BORDER + DIAMETER * 2, BORDER + DIAMETER))
sushiplate.setFill('white')
sushiplate.draw(win)

leftsushi = Circle(Point(BORDER - DIAMETER, BORDER), RADIUS)
leftsushi.setOutline('green')
leftsushi.setFill('orange')
leftsushi.draw(win)

rightsushi = Circle(Point(BORDER + DIAMETER, BORDER), RADIUS)
rightsushi.setOutline('green')
rightsushi.setFill('orange')
rightsushi.draw(win)

xmove = XMOVE_RIGHT
ymove = YMOVE_RIGHT

while True:
    # Move sushi

    center = sushiplate.getCenter()
    x, y = center.getX() + xmove, center.getY() + ymove

    if x > WIDTH - BORDER:
        xmove, ymove = XMOVE_DOWN, YMOVE_DOWN
    elif y > HEIGHT - BORDER:
        xmove, ymove = XMOVE_LEFT, YMOVE_LEFT
    elif x < BORDER:
        xmove, ymove = XMOVE_UP, YMOVE_UP
    elif y < BORDER:
        xmove, ymove = XMOVE_RIGHT, YMOVE_RIGHT

    for meal_object in (sushiplate, leftsushi, rightsushi):
        meal_object.move(xmove, ymove)

    update(60)
```